# Jquery binding to multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery binding to listen for paste action in certain text input elements. Is there a way inside of the function to get a reference to the actual element that triggered the event? My goal is to clear out the text in the input if anything is pasted inside out it, but 'this' doesn't seem to be correct.

Edit, the code has been updated:

```
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        $('.watchable').bind("paste", function() {
            alert('called!');
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
```

I am using JQuery 1.11.3. I see the alert, but the text is not cleared out.

Here is a jsFiddle demo. Paste any text into either of the 2 text fields, the alert displays, but the text in the text field is not cleared out.

https://jsfiddle.net/8bep1Lxh/

Comment: FYI as of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: I've verified that the event is triggered with an alert, but the text still doesn't clear out.

Comment: Please create jsfiddle demo

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8bep1Lxh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you'd like to *always* clear the field when pasting is attempted, then see the following updated examples:

**My Fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/8v08n4vx/

**Your Fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/jmap4jhy/

They prevent the default paste event *unless* the field is already empty.

If you'd like to prevent it altogether, simply remove the `if ($(this).val() !== ""){` statement.

**My Fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/7Lsr7j78/

**Your Fiddle** -https://jsfiddle.net/pzb9s7s4/

(However, you should think about the **possible negative impact** manipulating the **ubiquitious paste event** may have on user experience)

```
$('.watchable').on('paste', function (e) {

  //if field is not empty
  if ($(this).val() !== "") {

    // prevent default paste event
    e.preventDefault();
    // and clear field
    $(this).val('');

  }

});
```

---

Seeing as you're using a version of jQuery greater than 1.7, you should use `on` instead of `bind`.

**My Fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/ae8ufz7y/

**Your Updated Fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/83263j4e/

You simply need to add the following JavaScript:

```
$('.watchable').on('paste', function () {
  // on paste, clear input
  $(this).val('');
});
```

Here is the jQuery documentation on the `on` method:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @user1154644 - It's working fine for me. What is not working? If you paste something into the text field, the current text disappears and only the new text is present. Is that not happening for you or have I misunderstood your requirements?

Comment: @user1154644 - Also, which one isn't working...my fiddle or your one (or both)? Thanks.

Comment: either of them. when I go to your fiddle, I remove the text that is in the box, paste some text in, and it stays, it isn't cleared out

Comment: @user1154644 - I'm not sure I understand what you'd like. The fiddles work as follows: if you paste text into the textbox, the current text clears automatically and the new pasted text is the only text in the textbox. If try to paste something into an empty box (like you just described), the current text will be cleared (but seeing as there's no content, it just remains blank) and the new text will be pasted into the textbox. Try to paste something into my first example WITHOUT first manually clearing the textbox...only your pasted text will be present, the 'Lorem Ipsum' will be cleared.

Comment: @user1154644 - Let me know if that clears it up, or did you want it to behave differently?

Comment: @user1154644 - Did you want both input fields to be cleared when something is pasted into one of them? Or did you just want the current input field to be cleared? And if the fiddles still don't work after my description above, check you have javascript enabled on your browser.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear. the goal is for the text field to not allow text to be pasted into it, so if text is pasted into the field, the field should be cleared out, including what was pasted into it. clear it out completely.

Comment: @user1154644 - Ohhh, I think I understand. Check my updated answer above and see if it's closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: hmmm...still not executing the code inside the if block.

Comment: @user1154644 -  Do the fiddles work for you? Did you include the `(e)` in `function(e)`.

Comment: @user1154644 - I just tried the fiddles and they work as intended. Did you want to prevent pasting completely. So no one can ever paste in the input box...ever?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92550/discussion-between-user1154644-and-alvin-pascoe).

Comment: @user1154644 - Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better I think is to disable the paste event instead to clear out the text

```
$('.some-el').on('paste', function() {
  return false;
});
```

On paste event the value of input can't be captured(and modified) because the input change asynchronously with 'paste' event.

Just the next event can capture the value of input after paste event

```
$('.some-el').on('input', function() {});
```